# Absolute differences of images in OpenCV using a mask

Tags: c++, opencv

i need to compute some absolute differences on a set of images. Not all of the pixels should be taken into account. Unfortunately the opencv function [cv::absdiff()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#absdiff) doesnt provide a mask parameter. I also tried the [cv::subtract()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract) function which does provide a mask param, but this one doesnt compute absolute values and cuts the negative results to 0.

So does anyone knows a **fast** way to compute absolute differences on a **masked** image/matrix with opencv?

Thx!

Comment: You could multiply the mask by the images and use `absdiff` on that - surely there's got to be a "better" way though (seems a bit inefficient).

Comment: convert the images to 16-bit signed numbers, then apply `subtract`, find its `abs`, convert back to 8-bit.