# OpenCV - absdiff with a mask

Tags: c++, opencv, mask, mat

I am trying to calculate the absolute difference of two images using a mask so only a region of the images is considered in calculating the difference. But OpenCV does not have the mask part in [its function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#absdiff). I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421513/absolute-differences-of-images-in-opencv-using-a-mask) but did not work for me. I am trying to multiply the result in the mask so that only the specified region remains.

#### code:

```c
Mat region = //a grayscale image containing a region of 255 and the rest is zero
Mat img1, img2 = //two images of the same size as the region image and of type CV_8UC1
Mat mask = region / 255; //to make a binary mask
Mat difference = Mat::zeros(region .rows, region .cols, CV_8UC1);

cv::absdiff(img1, img2, difference);
difference = difference * mask;
if (!difference.empty()) imshow("difference", difference);
```

When I try this, I get an error.

#### error:

> Error: Assertion failed (a_size.width == len) in cv::gemm

which happens here:

```c
inline
Mat& Mat::operator = (const MatExpr& e)
{
    e.op->assign(e, *this);
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difference * mask` meaning that you are performing [Matrix multiplication](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/dab/group__core__hal__interface__matrix__multiplication.html), in this case the height of difference must be the same as width of mask, if you want to perform an [Element wise multiplication](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a385c09827713dc3e6d713bfad8460706) you should call `difference.mul(mask)`